# Is it all right to spy on students while they're using their accounts?

Tags: privacy

So you might be thinking that my school invades the privacy of the students, but the question is at what point should it be private?
The reason I am asking this is because one of my classmates just got caught searching for illegal things (messed up things like that page with a 34) by checking into the browser history. Now the accounts need to be checked once in a while, so is it okay to spy on students like this?

Comment: Depends on the country, institution, and user agreements. Where I work they can do anything the want with my work computer.

Comment: Just to be clear, "rule 34" is not all illegal material. So please clarify whether your country has extreme porn laws or whether they were viewing really problematic material (or maybe there's some other website you're referring to I'm unfamiliar with).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Checking tthe browser history is probably not OK, at least ethically, and surely not OK on a private computer. On a university computer it is debatable, but not needed. Reading mail would be clearly wrong (ethically) and illegal in many countries.

If the university network was used, the browser history is not needed. The University surely monitors the traffic over the university network and knows which computer accesses what, like any other ISP would know. There are surely rules on what can the university network be used to and following these rules can be enforced.

Similarly, university data storage may be dedicated to only certain kind of study and work related data and other stuff like personal photographs (more likely to be ignored), mp3 collection or downloaded films (less likely to be ignored) may be forbidden and even searched for by some automatic scripts.

Comment: Nitpick: with SSL (which is the standard these days), traffic monitoring tells which computer accesses which *domain*, not the full webpage address. They may know that you accessed The Pirate Bay, but not what you downloaded --- what if you torrented [Ubuntu 21.10](https://thepiratebay0.org/torrent/54358176/Ubuntu_21.10_Desktop_(64-bit))?

Comment: It's always been made pretty clear to me in the US that your institutional email is not private, and in fact is subject to freedom of information requests. Not that people go looking just because

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- It may be the case in the land of the free... In other countries, however: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/european-companies-must-alert-employees-if-work-email-is-being-monitored/ After GDPR: https://www.lexology.com/commentary/employment-immigration/hungary/schoenherr/access-to-employee-emails-enhanced-authority-control And let's not forget that students are often not employees.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Custer has already written, "it depends" on country where this took place, and possibly on other things.

Your post isn't clear whether your classmate was using a university resource like a computer, or perhaps using a university network.  If your classmate was using university resources, including university computer or network, then what the university did was probably OK.  It is not unusual for a university to monitor how their resources were used.